# I want to restrict textarea characters length to 150 characters, My system.xml code is below :

Tags: magento

I want to restrict textarea characters length to 150 characters, My system.xml code is below :

```
...
<orderPlaceMessage translate="label">
    <label>Message for order place: </label>
    <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

    {how to limit character length }

</orderPlaceMessage>
...
```

Comment: Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please find two solutions below.**

**Solution 1:-**

Add the following to the `<orderPlaceMessage>` element:

```
<validate>validate-length maximum-length-150</validate>
```

> This will add these validation CSS classes used by prototype.js. If
>   you enter a longer value, you will see this generic validation
>   message:

[image: Text length does not satisfy specified text range]

> So it is a good idea to add a comment as well to let the user know
>   what this range *is*:

```
<comment>Maximum length: 150 characters</comment>
```

> If the limit is important for data integrity, you should also add
>   server-side validation, using a backend model. Digital Pianism already
>   linked a tutorial for this:
>   http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_config_validation
>
> And if you want to know more about the various options in the
>   system.XML, there is:
>   http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial

**Solution 2:-**

> Please used below jQuery script for limit character length :

```
jQuery("#sms_cnfg_advanced_settings textarea").keypress(function(event){
    var maxLength = 160;
    var length = this.value.length;
    if (length >= maxLength)
     {
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxLength);
        alert(maxLength + ' characters allowed, excess characters trimmed');
     }
});

jQuery("#sms_cnfg_advanced_settings textarea").on('keyup',function(){
    jQuery('.charnum').remove();
    var maxLength = 160;
    var length = this.value.length;

     var count=maxLength-length;
     jQuery('<span class="charnum">' +count+' Characters left</span>').insertAfter(jQuery(this));

});
```

**I Hope it's helpful for you.**

Comment: Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312383/discussions-on-edit-review/312387#312387 - especially the part about using quote-formatting only for quotes....

Comment: Thank You for explaining in details, working fine for me.@Umesh

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<validate>` tag to restrict textarea characters length to 150 characters.

```
<validate>validate-length maximum-length-150</validate>
```

You can  add a comment as well to let the user know what is the desired range.